# Load shellcode from file to char* comes strange characters in end of text

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, char, shellcode

I have a `char array[]` and is like following:

```
// MessageBox
   char xcode[] = "\x31\xc9\x64\x8b\x41\x30\x8b\x40\xc\x8b\x70\x14\xad\x96\xad\x8b\x58\x10\x8b\x53\x3c\x1\xda\x8b\x52\x78\x1\xda\x8b\x72\x20\x1\xde\x31\xc9\x41\xad\x1\xd8\x81\x38\x47\x65\x74\x50\x75\xf4\x81\x78\x4\x72\x6f\x63\x41\x75\xeb\x81\x78\x8\x64\x64\x72\x65\x75\xe2\x8b\x72\x24\x1\xde\x66\x8b\xc\x4e\x49\x8b\x72\x1c\x1\xde\x8b\x14\x8e\x1\xda\x31\xc9\x53\x52\x51\x68\x61\x72\x79\x41\x68\x4c\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4c\x6f\x61\x64\x54\x53\xff\xd2\x83\xc4\xc\x59\x50\x51\x66\xb9\x6c\x6c\x51\x68\x33\x32\x2e\x64\x68\x75\x73\x65\x72\x54\xff\xd0\x83\xc4\x10\x8b\x54\x24\x4\xb9\x6f\x78\x41\x0\x51\x68\x61\x67\x65\x42\x68\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x54\x50\xff\xd2\x83\xc4\x10\x68\x61\x62\x63\x64\x83\x6c\x24\x3\x64\x89\xe6\x31\xc9\x51\x56\x56\x51\xff\xd0";
```

Then i had inserted all this content of variable above into a file (file with UTF-8 format and content without the `""`) and tried load this way:

```
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("shellcode.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

    size_t file_size_in_byte = infile.tellg();
    char* xcode = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size_in_byte);

    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    infile.read(xcode, file_size_in_byte);

    printf("%s\n", xcode); // << prints content of xcode after load from file

    if (infile.eof()) {
        size_t bytes_really_read = infile.gcount();
    }
    else if (infile.fail()) {
    }

    infile.close();
```

I'm seeing some strange characters in end of text see:

[image: strange characters]

What is need to fix it?

Comment: `"%s"` format requires that the string is null-terminated.

Comment: Pop quiz: every C-style string ends with a special character, do you know what it is?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, with `cout << xcode << endl;` i also can see same behavior.

Comment: @Coringa -- The `cout` being used that way will also require null-termination.  Don't use functions that rely on null-termination, that's the bottom line.  See my answer.

Comment: What equivalent to `char array[]`, since that this can be initialized/created already with size of file?

Comment: I'm seeing that `char* variable` isn't.

Comment: Yes, and `cout << xcode << endl` also expects a C-style string. Once again: do you know which special character must appear at the end of a C-style string? Which part of your code makes sure that it's there?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, then you is saying me that: `char* xcode = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size_in_byte);` is the same that declare `char xcode[]` (this last with difference that not is defininf a size)?

Comment: No, I am not saying anything of that sort (its true that `xcode` has it, but that's irrelevant). But, since you mention `malloc`, why is this even using `malloc` in the first place? This is C++, not C. In C++ we can use strings or containers, like vectors, to manage all the memory for us, automatically freeing it after use. If your intent to write C++ code, then you should write C++ code, not C code sprinkled throughout an otherwise C++ code base.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, then in C++ how initialize a `char array[]` with filesize, beeing that this requires a const value?. This is the reason to `malloc` on my code. Beyond this, i'm have a [routine](https://github.com/secrary/InfectPE/blob/489eef57d629645ae496d0bcf50b7b3c54de089e/InfectPE/PE.cpp#L303) where [is expected](https://github.com/secrary/InfectPE/blob/489eef57d629645ae496d0bcf50b7b3c54de089e/InfectPE/InfectPE.cpp#L55) a `char array[]`, not a `char*` (`char* xcode`) to be honest.

Comment: This is what `std::vector` is for. Your C++ textbook should have a chapter that explains how to use a vector, how to resize it to "filesize", or any other size, and have C++ do everything for you. Modern C++ code doesn't even need to use C++'s `new`, much less C's `malloc`.

Comment: And `vector` not is the same that `array[]`, not will be useful.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the routine requires a `char array[]`, `vector` not is the same. See my previous comment please.

Comment: Anything that expects an `array[]` will be able to use a `std::vector`, guaranteed. It is logically impossible for any C++ function or method to require a `char array[]` as a parameter, because you'll be surprised to learn that it is impossible to pass `char array[]` as parameter to a function or a method. It's not possible to do it in C or C++. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Here's something you thought was impossible: `std::vector<char> xcode; xcode.resize(file_size_in_bytes);
    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    infile.read(&xcode[0], file_size_in_byte);`. I do recommend that you should spend a little bit more time with a C++ textbook, learning how to use vectors.

Comment: Yes, I'm "sure". You'll be surprised to learn that all of those functions really take `const char *` or `char *` as parameters, and not arrays. You can ***pass*** arrays. But they are ***always*** converted to pointers. That's the only way that C++ works. So arrays are ***never*** required, and can always be replaced by a vector, which will produce a completely identical pointer, on demand. You can use an electron microscope, and still won't be able to tell the difference between a vector-produced pointer, and an array. Isn't C++ amazing?

Comment: @Coringa [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5a797199afc97ad).  A `std::vector` can be used since it stores its data in a (dynamic) array.  That's why the `foo()` function works for both.

Comment: And another useful feature of C++ that you should be aware of is that `std::string`s and `std::vector<char>`  have so few differences between them, that they can be mostly substituted for each other, except that the I/O library only knows about `std::string`s, so you simply replace `std::vector<char>` with a `std::string`, load it from a file in ***exactly*** the same way, and no C-style terminating character is necessary. And `malloc` or `free` is still not required, for any reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `printf` format specifier `"%s"` requires that the string is null-terminated.  In your case, the null-terminator just happens to be after those characters you're seeing, but nothing guarantees where the null is unless you put one there.

Since you're using C++, one way to print the characters is to use the [write()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function available for streams:

```
#include <iostream>
//...
std::cout.write(xcode, file_size_in_bytes);
```

The overall point is this -- if you have a character array that is not null-terminated and contains data, you must either:

1. Put the null in the right place before using the array in functions that look for the null-terminator or
2. Use functions that state how many characters to process from the character array.

The answer above uses item 2.